# HTML form with results on same page with isset

Tags: php, html

I am looking to have the results of a query to be posted on the same HTML page that data is entered into. I believe that this can be done with the isset() command, but I don't truly understand what it does and what is telling my page to go to a new php url to give me my table of data.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="results.php" method="post">
<table border="0">
<td align="center"><head>Orders</head>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter order number:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="enter" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my current code. Does the

```
<form action="results.php" method="post">
```

Line tell the code to post to a new page? Does

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

go somewhere in the code in my html file or in my results.php file?

Answer (score 1):

If your form is on index.php page than first thing to do is to change action="results.php" to action="index.php" so you are not redirected to result.php page. Than you can do something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        echo "Order number - " . $_POST['enter'];
    }
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table border="0">
<td align="center"><head>Orders</head>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter order number:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="enter" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want also fill form fields with entered value than you could do this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        echo "Order number - " . $_POST['enter'];
    }
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table border="0">
<td align="center"><head>Orders</head>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter order number:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="enter" size="3" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['enter'])?$_POST['enter']:'';?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same file to show the results,

1. you have to rename the .html of the current file to .php
2. use `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">` instead of `<form action="results.php" method="post">`
3. now you add `if(isset($_POST))` somewhere in the same file

you can add html code as usual to a .php file but you cannot add php code to a .html file

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
if(isset($_POST['enter']))
```

also if you want to execute the output when "enter" field doesn't have a blank value, then you can use :

```
if(isset($_POST['enter']) && $_POST['enter']!="")
```

also keep the form action value to the same page like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

OR

```
<form action="<?php print($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: where does the isset code go?

Comment: top of the page between <?php and ?> tags